# Presigned URL image upload with Google Cloud Storage does not upload image correctly (MERN + React Native)

Tags: react-native, axios, google-cloud-storage, expo, pre-signed-url

I am able to generate signedUrls from my server and send it back to my React Native (expo) client.

The client is also able to send a put request to the signedUrl with an image object that includes a uri to an image stored on the device.

The problem is that the image saved in Google Cloud appears corrupt. I imagine there must be additional settings I need to add to get the image to upload properly.

**Server Code To Generate URL**

```
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const storage = new Storage({keyFilename: "keys.json"});
const bucketName = "bucket";
const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
const { v4 } = require("uuid");

async upload(req, res, next) {
const options = {
        action: "write",
        expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes,
        contentType: "image/jpeg"
      };
const fileName = `1234/${v4()}.jpg`
const [url] = await bucket.file(fileName).getSignedUrl(options);
res.send(url)
}
```

**Example of presigned URL from server**

```
const url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/1234/00bae114-87e4-4647-94d3-31115453e9bd.jpg?GoogleAccessId=id%40num.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1587297408&Signature=signaturecode"
```

**Example of an image object**

```
const image = {
  "name": "IMG_4831.JPG",
  "type": "image/jpeg",
  "uri": "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=AC24211D-E728-44D2-8B00-29EF04EC74E0&ext=JPG"
}
```

**React Native code to send image through presigned URL**

```
import axios from "axios";
const image = {uri, type: "image/jpeg", name };

await axios.put(url, image, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "image/jpeg" }
      });
```

Comment: Could you try changing the contentType to something else like plain/text? It could be an issue related to this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use expo `FileSystem.uploadAsync(url, fileUri, options)` instead of axios and it works.

Comment: Did you do anything fancy regarding options? for me this currently returns a 403, while it works fine when uxing axios (but sending a Buffer instead which is not ideal)

Comment: Oh man - this is amazing. We were trying to use so many workarounds to issues with expo crashing with iOS https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2402 .... using `FileSystem.uploadAsync` works much nicer!